# Make span inside <a> element have independent link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" target="_self">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
      the 1500s.<span>...more</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px
}
span {
  color: green !important;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('span').click(function(){
    location.href = "www.google.com";
});
```

My question is, How to make my `span` redirect to google.com when I click this `span`?

Comment: use `return false;` `$('span').click(function(e){
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
return false;
});`

Comment: Well, I advice not to use Block-level element in Inline-level element.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp
In your case <a> is Inline-level element and <div> and <p> are Block level elements!

Comment: it doesn't work guradio, do you have another options?

Comment: Hi @NavdeepSingh. Can you please show me, how the code should be look like? because, I want all of the div.container element redirect to yahoo if clicked, except span element

Comment: Hi, all I was tried all of your advice , but still doesn't work. 
Can you please check the following fiddle link: 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Naticap/7yahnonx/62/)

Answer (score 2):

Adding preventDefault solves this.

```
$('span').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = "https://www.google.com";
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work @Thu Sama, do yo have another option?

Comment: Oh it doesn't work? Try adding. `e.stopPropagation();` too under preventDefault. Using preventDefault worked for me though.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, just preventing the default action the browser makes on the `span` element with `e.preventDefault()` is enough:

```
$('span').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work @Mamun, do yo have another option? I was copied your code on my fidle but still doesn't work

Comment: @bagongpct, I did check the code in my environment and working as expected. I guess there might be some other issues where you implementing this.

Comment: Hii @Mamun, can you please check the following link [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Naticap/7yahnonx/62/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me:

```
        $('span').click(function () {
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        });
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Han,  Your solution doesn't work too. do yo have another options?

Comment: @bagongpct OK, so let me confirm this: you wish to redirect to google.com IN the span and not a full page redirect?

Comment: Hi @Han K. Yes, correct I want redirect to google.com when the span clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
$('span').click(function(){
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Dui,  I was applied your advice but it still doesn't work. do yo have another options?